# Ввод строки(массива символов) с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, c

```
char A[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cin >> A[i];
}
```

Я не знаю начальный размер строки, ввёл случайное большое число. Когда записываю строку с помощью `cin` запись не прекращается при нажатии `Enter`, пока не введу все 1000 символов. Как при нажатии `Enter` прекращать ввод?

Comment: Вы в принципе не знаете нужный размер массива или его можно рассчитать по ходу программы? Если 2й вариант: char* data = new char[n]; Где n - нужная длинна массива

Comment: `string s; cin>>s;`

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать по разному, но читать строку до символа переноса строки, думаю проще всего:

```
char A[1000];
cin.getline(A, 1000, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

После cin в цикле ставить проверку

```
if(A[i] == '\n') {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используется getch - получение данных о нажатой клавише

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int key;

    char A[1000] = { };
    //получает данные о нажатой клавише
    key = _getch();
    int i = 0;
    // сам цикл, которые выполняется до нажатия Enter
    while (i != 999 && key != 13) {
        key = _getch();
        if (key == 13) {
            break;
        } else {
            cin >> A[i];
        }
        if (i != 999) {
            keybd_event(13, 0, 0, 0);
            // имитация повторного нажатия Enter,
            // чтобы совершился выход из цикла
            keybd_event(13, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

После нажатия Enter выполнение цикла прекращается, программа идёт дальше

*P.S немного поправил код, чтобы он работал корректно если массив заполняется полностью.*

Comment: Доп информация: 13 - код кнопки Enter

Comment: Ошибка C4996 'getch': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _getch.

Comment: Нужно поменять все getch на  _getch

Comment: Немного исправил код, можете использовать

Answer (score -1):

```
char A[1000];
cin.getline(a, 1001);
cout << A;
```

Comment: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ выводиться тысяча таких символов

Comment: Странно. У меня все работает.

Comment: А если вместо cin.getline() поставить cin.get()? Попробуй...

Comment: char a[1000];
cin.get(a, 1001);
cout << a;

Comment: мб в другой части кода ошибка
void cStyle(){
 char A[1000];
 char newA[1000];
 cin.getline(A, 1001);
 for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
  newA[i] == A[i + 1];
  cout << newA[i];
 }
 cout << endl<<endl;
}

Comment: почему для буффера в 1000 элементов в getline вы передаёте 1001?

Comment: Последний элемент не записывается. Если бы я записал 1000, то записалось бы максимум 999. Если вам надо, можете 1000 оставить.

Comment: последний элемент не записывается, потому что нужно оставить место для завершающего символа '\0'. Написав 1001 для буфера в 1000 этот символ записывается (если введено >=1000 символов)  за пределы буфера и приводит к UB

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: К сведению, в данном случае cout << A; выведет указатель на массив, а не его значение. Для вывода значений нужно использовать for

Comment: С вашим 1001 теоретически возможен выход за границу массива.